# MYSQL IN Clause Issue

Tags: mysql

There are a lot of questions posted on stackoverflow that are almost same like my problem but I found no working solution. I have a table **message** and entries are:

```
id | Message | Status
1  |  Hello  |  1
2  |  Hiiii  |  0
4  |  Works  |  1
```

I have another table which gives ids 1,2,3 and I want to find the status of all these entries from **message** table. What I want is if an id doesn't exist in **message** table then it should return null for that id if I use IN clause to find all status. I want following result:

```
id | Status
1  | 1
2  | 0
3  | null
```

I have been using IN clause but didn't get working output. Then I got a solution on stackoverflow and tried this query

```
SELECT `id`,`status` FROM ( SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 3) ids LEFT OUTER JOIN message ON ids.ID = message.id
```

But this query is not giving the expected results. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how your query would work.  The column `id` should be ambiguous in the `select` (unless your database is case sensitive).  Try this:

```
SELECT ids.ID, m.status
FROM ( SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 3
     ) ids LEFT OUTER JOIN
     message m
     ON ids.ID = m.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for it. But when I add ORDER BY FIELD(ids.ID, 3,1,2) at the end of this query then it doesn't give the results in 3,1,2 order. Any help on this?

Comment: Your `order by` clause should work.  Are you removing the semicolon at the end of the `from` clause?

Comment: No, I am not removing. And it is order by FIELD because I want output in the same order that I have posted in my comment i.e 3,1,2

Comment: Query for my table is: SELECT * from ( select e.`seen_by_worker`,ids.ID as `task_id`,ids.ID as `sort` FROM (select 58 as ID union all select 59 as ID union all select 83 as ID union all select 155 as ID union all select 156 as ID union all select 157 as ID union all select 57 as ID) ids LEFT JOIN `e_projectInbox` e ON ids.ID = e.`task_id`  ORDER BY FIELD(ids.ID, 58,59,83,155,156,157,57), seen_by_worker desc) u group by u.sort;

Comment: If you want to `order by` something, then it needs to go in the outer query, not a subquery.  Put the `order by` after the `group by`.

Comment: Results are coming in ascending sequence, 57,58,59,83,155,156,157. I want them in the sequence that in order by.